# How to make response of request module nodejs to object?

Tags: node.js

I'm using [request npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

my response return format such as "string". How to convert response to object?

Answer (score -1):

I found answer

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info ) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```